# PHP - Post Method not passing complete value

Tags: php, string, input

I have a variable $string associated to a string in the form of a csv file from the fputcsv. The $strin variable looks like this:

```
$string='Epitope/Cluster,"Epitope ID" LEYIPEITLPVIAALSIAES,"35768,28983,35767" NILMQYIKANSKFIGITELK,"52929,27213,44284,52930" DIIDDFTNESSQKTTIDKIS,8659 LINSTKIYSYFPSVISKVNQ,"36647,31484" ILFLQWVRDIIDDFTNESSQ,"27043,79996"';
```

I am trying to pass this string to another php file called csv_file.php. What I am using is:

```
echo'<form method="POST" action="csv_file.php">';
echo'<input type="hidden" name="csv_content" value='.$string.'>';
echo'<input type="submit" value="Download">';
echo'</form>';
```

But when I print the variable in the other php page using:

```
$csv_content = $_POST['csv_content'];
print($csv_content);
```

I get always get the string printed until the ver first white space it has, so it prints:

```
Epitope/Cluster,Epitope
```

Do you know how to correct this issue?
Thank you

Comment: Look at the HTML code generated by your script, you should notice something about the content of the `value` attribute … and how it differs from the notation you used for other attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `"` in your value attribute you should use `'` around them correctly.
At the moment your `'` only breaks the PHP String.

Better:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="csv_content" value=\''.$string.'\'>';
```

It's maybe not the most beautiful solution but it shouldn't break your formatting.

Answer (score 0):

First, escape the double quotes in `$string` with html entities. Then, surround the string with double quotes:

```
$string = str_replace('"', '&quot;', $string);
echo '<input type="hidden" name="csv_content" value="'.$string.'">';
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that your value is not string encapsulated in your markup.

```
value='.$string.'
```

Change this

```
value="'.$string.'"
```

Comment: If I do that it prints "Epitope/Cluster," so I am still not sure how to fix it